# Is it possible to do these in a single step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

1.

```
    json_string = json.dumps(
        df.to_dict(orient='records'),
        indent=4
    )
```

2.

```
    json_string = json_string.replace('NaN', 'null')
```

Is there a way to do these 2 in a single step?

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for the response. I liked the way you did it with simplejson.dumps() but I also found out that using 'allow_nan=False' in json.dumps() does the job as well. The reason why I didn't wanna use to_json() is because though I did json.dumps() on it with 'indent=4', it didn't return an indented json string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better is use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) - there are also replace missing values to `null`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a',
                                np.nan,
                                'c']})

json_string = df.to_json(orient='records')
print (json_string)
[{"col":"a"},{"col":null},{"col":"c"}]
```

Your solution should be changed with [`simplejson`](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/):

```
import simplejson

json_string = simplejson.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records'), ignore_nan=True)
print (json_string)
[{"col": "a"}, {"col": null}, {"col": "c"}]
```

Or replace missing values to `None`s:

```
json_string = json.dumps(
        df.mask(df.isna(), None).to_dict(orient='records'),
        indent=4,
    )

print (json_string)

[
    {
        "col": "a"
    },
    {
        "col": null
    },
    {
        "col": "c"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain the funtion calls:

```
json_string = json.dumps(
    mergedropped_df.to_dict(orient='records'),
    indent=4
).replace('NaN', 'null')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually looking for some other function that could do the whole thing with a keyword argument given.